# AssignProcessToJobObject Failing The Handle is Invalid

Tags: c++, windows, jar, parent-child

Im creating a job with CreateJobObjectA(), then creating a new process with CreateProcessA(), and when I try to assign the new process to the job I have created with AssignProcessToJobObject() it returns 0. So I GetLastError() and im getting a value of 6. Which according to Windows systems error code means The Handle is invalid. Heres my code.

```
HANDLE job = CreateJobObjectA( NULL, "jobName" );
if( job == NULL )
{
    printf( "Job is NULL" );
}
else
{
    JOBJECT_EXTENDED_LIMIT_INFORMATION jeli = { 0 };
    jeli.BasicLimitInformation.LimitFlags = JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_KILL_ON_JOB_CLOSE;
    if( 0 == SetInformationJobObject( job, JobObjectExtendedLimitInformation, &jeli, sizeof(jeli)))
    {
        printf("Could not SetInformationJobObject\n");
    }
}
if( CreateProcessA( "C:\\Windows\\SysWOW64\\cmd.exe", "/c server.bat", NULL, NULL, TRUE, 0, NULL, NULL, &info, &processInfo))
{
    printf("CreateProcess succeeded.\n");
    if( job != NULL )
    {
        HANDLE derp =  processInfo.hProcess;
        if( derp != NULL )
        {
            if( 0 == AssignProcessToJobObject( job, derp ))
            {
                printf("Could not AssignProcessToObject\n");
                DWORD err = GetLastError();
                printf("derp");
            }
        }
    }
    //Can we free handles now? Not sure about this.
    CloseHandle(processInfo.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(processInfo.hThread);
}
```

The bat file is doing what it is supposed to be doing and launching a jar that runs a server. I just dont get how my Handle is invalid. Any help would be amazing. Or possibly a different way to do this?

I want to launch this new process and have it be a child process so when my main process crashes the server closes also.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a race condition.  If `cmd.exe` exits before you call `AssignProcessToJobObject` it won't work (I'm not sure what error code you get in that scenario).

Start the process suspended using the `CREATE_SUSPENDED` flag and don't resume it until you've already assigned it to the job.